# System print by default else message in php

Tags: php

I write these code for searching functionality in my project.
    If user enter correct zip code it show one form if zip code is wrong it show some message which i write in else condition.
    But by default is show the else message when user enter first time on page.
    I want to show that(message which i write in else condition) message if user enter wrong zip code what i do?Any suggestion.

```
<small>Enter your zipcode to book our service</small>
    <?php if($this->isAllowedZipcode=="Matched"){?>  
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } else
    { ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <p>Sorry but our services are not available in your area. We are working hard to cover as much area as we can. Thank you for using the system.</p>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: your code seems to be incomplete, the if conditions used by your are not clear, please recheck your code

Comment: `<?php } ?>` ends your `if`. `<?php } else` continues __some other `if`__

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be incorrect/incomplete, but as per your requirements, you could do it as follow:

```
    <small>Enter your zipcode to book our service</small>
    <?php if($this->isAllowedZipcode=="Matched"){ ?>  
         <div class="row">
                //ZIPCODE MATCHED
         </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <p>Sorry but our services are not available in your area. We are working hard to cover as much area as we can. Thank you for using the system.</p>
            </div>
       </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: it is just an idea to solve your problem, you will have to work on the " if " condition, you should learn about how if else conditions work in php

Answer (score -1):

You can use `elseif` condition when you can test if the zip code is set, not only `else`.

```
<small>Enter your zipcode to book our service</small>
    <?php if($this->isAllowedZipcode=="Matched"){?>  
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <?php } elseif (isset($inputZipCode))
    { ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <p>Sorry but our services are not available in your area. We are working hard to cover as much area as we can. Thank you for using the system.</p>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: you are doing the same mistake as of OP, what's the role of this extra brace " } " ?